# Can this be solve using modular arithmetic? $k$ is prime $\Rightarrow$ $8k+1$ is prime

Tags: prime-numbers, proof-writing, modular-arithmetic

Is the following statement true or false?

> $\forall k  \in \mathbb{N}, k$ is prime $\Rightarrow$ $8k+1$ is prime

The answer is that the statement is false because if $k=7$, then $k$ is prime but $8k+1=57$ is not prime.

Is there are way to solve this problem using modular arithmetic? If yes, what is the process of solving it and how do I select the right modulo?

Comment: I see nothing to solve. The problem asks if the assertion is true or false. Your one counterexample is sufficient to prove that it is false.

Comment: Agreed with Perry. Plus, when $k=11$, $8k+1=89$ is prime so it can happen that $8k+1$ is prime when $k$ is.

Comment: Well, I found the counterexample by sequentially going through the prime numbers (in hindsight, I could have stopped at $k=5$ too). I am just thinking of a possibility where the expression would only be false for some really large value of $k$. In that case, is testing the statement with all the possible prime numbers the only way to prove that it is false? And what if the statement is actually true, how does one prove it?

Comment: It's going to be hard to tell you how to construct a proof of this statement because the statement isn't true. I could give you many incorrect proofs if you'd like. ajotatxe's answer is an elegant way of proving the statement false, using modular arithmetic and Dirichlet's theorem to provide infinitely many counterexamples without doing an explicit search for them.

Comment: @Nick ajotatxe answer is actually what I am looking for. I suppose I should have asked: how do I prove the statement is false using only modular arithmetic

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are infinitely many primes $p\equiv1\pmod 3$ ([Dirichlet's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet's_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions)). And for these primes, $8p+1\equiv 0\pmod 3$, so $8p+1$ is not prime.

I am not sure if this is what you are asking for.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I am asking for. Thank you! So one has to know the Dirichlet's theorem in order to be able to select the right modulo. But given some arbitrary expression in the conclusion, say $k^2+8k-5$, mod 3 will not always work, would it? Can you please point me to some sites/resources that discuss how to select the right mod for these kind of problems?

Comment: To select the modulo, I would simply substitute $k$ by some integer: $k^2+8k-5=_{k=2}31$. Then, there are infinitely many primes $\equiv 2\pmod {31}$. For each value that $k$ takes among these primes, the result is a multiple of $31$.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is you can just use the first $k$ in your sequence of primes as modulus.

If for some prime $p$, the sequence of numbers $k_n$ defined by

$$k_n = \begin{cases}p, & n = 0\\8k_{n-1}+1, &n > 0\end{cases}$$

are all primes, we will have

$$k_{p-1} = 8^{p-1} p + 8^{p-2} + 8^{p-2} + \cdots 1 = 8^{p-1} p + \frac{8^{p-1}-1}{7}$$

is also a prime. If $p \ne 2$ nor $7$, then $\gcd(p,8) = 1$ and Fermat little theorem
leads to

$$p | 8^{p-1} - 1 \quad\implies\quad
p | \frac{8^{p-1}-1}{7} \quad\implies\quad 
p | k_{p-1}$$

This contradict with the assumption the sequence $k_n$ start at $k_0 = p$ are all primes.
Since we know the sequence $k_n$ starting with $k_0 = 2$ or $7$ are not all primes. We can conclude start with any prime $p$, the operation $k \mapsto 8k+1$ will fail to produce a prime after some finite step.